# Behaviour percentages changed in Titanium after setting Default Unit as dp

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

In my portrait Android App I've always used a fixed percentage of the width for my images.

Automatically the Height was calculated to mantaing the original ratio of the image.

For example:

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'/images/myimage.png',
  width: "80%",
});
win.add(image);
win.open();
```

But, After changing the default unit to dp:

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

This behaviour is not working anymore.

The image is displayed normally, ignoring `width: '80%'`. 
Tried to setting only Height too with no results.

The only way is setting both percentages, so the image is displayed whitout ignoring the percentages.

Notes:

- The same occurs with numbers in place of the percentages.
- Tried setting one of the size with **'auto'/Ti.UI.Size/Ti.UI.Fill** with no result.

So anyone knows if this is a bug? Is there a workaraound?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to get the height / width of the screen and do some simple maths to calculate 80% of the screen.

You can get the width and height like this:

```
var height = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
    width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
```